# Manually calculating available width is incorrect when display and font sizes are large

Tags: android, textview, font-size, android-fonts, android-chips

I have a ViewGroup with a Chip as a child with no horizontal siblings.

I try to calculate the available width before choosing which text to set inside the Chip.

```
final View parent = (View) getParent();
final int parentPaddingLeft = parent.getPaddingLeft();
final int parentPaddingRight = parent.getPaddingRight();
final int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
final int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
final int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
final int rightMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin;
final int textViewSafetyPadding = 20;
final int currentTextMaxWidth =
    parentWidth
        - (textViewSafetyPadding
            + parentPaddingLeft
            + parentPaddingRight
            + paddingLeft
            + paddingRight
            + leftMargin
            + rightMargin);
```

It all worked well, but when I change the OS display size and font size to the largest - I see the chosen text doesn't fit inside the Chip.

Even though the paint measurement and chip actual width show it should fit.

Chip's width onDraw == 550pxl
chosen text requires 442pxl

and

```
paint.measureText(chipText) <= textMaxWidth
```

Any idea of abnormal extra padding when font size and display size are bigger than default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Chip` is a `compoundButton`, I should have subtracted `Chip#getCompoundPaddingRight/Left` instead of `getPaddingRight/Left`.